# repeat old value when using setState in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list view for chat that has reverse: true mode. In this list, I have a statefullWidget. When I update the list related to the list view and add a new item to it, it shows the content of the previous item instead of the new item and repeats.
This problem only occurs when I have a statefullWidget inside the list view and the reverse: true is also active!

listView code:

```
    ListView.builder(
                          controller: chatPageController.scrollController,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                          reverse: true,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: messages.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            Message message = messages[index];
                            print('now ti ${message.path} ${message.id}');
                            return Container(
                              width: 200,
                              child: getMessageView(message,
                                  chatPageController.conversation),
                            );
                          },
                        );
```

messages code and how updating:

```
  
  List<Message> messages = [];

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    messages = chatPageController.collections;
    chatPageController.createdMessage.listen((p0) {
      dmp('createdMessage', data: p0);
      if (p0 != null) {
        setState(() {
          messages.add(p0);
        });
      }
    });
}
```

EDIT:
getMessageView is return an stateFullWidget

Answer (score 0):

i solve it by adding key in listView and in stateFullWIdget inside listView like below

```
...
GetMessageView(message,
  chatPageController.conversation, key: ValueKey(message.path))
    ...
```

and stateFullWidget like below

```
class OwnMessageCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const OwnMessageCard({Key? key, required this.message}) : super(key: key);
...
}
```